# Get Specific Indices from a Grid in numpy

Tags: python

I run the following code:

```
    import numpy as np
    Z = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
    print(Z[[0,1],[0,2]])
```

Z is:

0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8

I expected to get the values 1 and 2 but got 0 and 5, so I don't understand how this indexing works.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Z[[0,1],[0,2]] returns Z[0,0] and Z[1,2], that's why you get 0 and 5.

Comment: thanks, I thought each pair refers to a different element and did not know it is being unpacked in this form.